# How to change status bar color when app is in background?

Tags: android, android-statusbar

I am able to change the status bar color to green but when home button is clicked when app is in background, status bar goes back to its original color. I want to retain the status bar color even when the app is in background. Like status bar is green when there is a call connected.

This is my code to change the status color.

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    getWindow().setStatusBarColor(
        ContextCompat.getColor(context,R.color.colorAccent)); 
}
```

Comment: post your code .

Answer (score 0):

The `onPause()` and `onResume()` methods are called when the application is brought to the background and into the foreground again. However, they are also called when the application is started for the first time and before it is killed.

There isn't any direct approach to get the application status while in the background or foreground, but even I have faced this issue and found the solution with `onWindowFocusChanged` and `onStop`.
For more details please check [this.](http://vardhan-justlikethat.blogspot.in/2013/05/android-solution-to-detect-when-android.html)

Happy coding!!

Comment: As you suggested, i added my code to change the status color                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                getWindow().setStatusBarColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this,R.color.colorAccent));
            }.....................................the status color shrinks along with the app